# multidimensional array to database in python

Tags: python, arrays, database, list, sqlite

I am trying to figure out a way to put a two dimensional array (using python) into an sqlite database. My array:

```
['hello', 'hello', 'hello'], ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
```

What I want is for each tuple of 'hello's would a new row with each 'hello' being its own attribute. I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is even possible (I hope it is). I tried following a few other posts but I keep getting the error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Does anyone know how to insert a multidimensional array into a sqlite database? Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

array2d = [['hello' for x in xrange(3)] for x in xrange(3)] 

var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(array2d))

conn = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE sample (Name TEXT, Line_1 TEXT, Line_2 TEXT)''')

query_string = 'INSERT INTO sample VALUES (%s);' % var_string

c.execute(query_string, array2d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`cursor.executemany()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) to insert a sequence of rows in one go:

```
query_string = 'INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?, ?)'

c.executemany(query_string, array2d)
conn.commit()
```

Don't forget to `conn.commit()` the transaction.

I've not bothered with formatting the SQL parameters here, for demonstration purposes; you don't really want to do so here anyway, as your number of columns is fixed at well (from the `CREATE TABLE` definition).

Comment: Thanks for response. I got rid of the error message but I when look into sample.db using SQLite Database Browser the data fields are empty.

Comment: You need to commit as well. :-)